# Python re.findall avoiding eagerness

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a problem when the engine finds the first alternative in regex pattern, it stops analyzing the further string positions on the right. For instance, I have the following example:

In the string `ABC SCHOOL FOUNDATION COOPERATIVE PARTNERSHIP` I'd like to get `['foundation cooperative partnership']` as a match. However, I am getting `['foundation', 'cooperative']` because the engine finds `foundation` and then continue with the following word `cooperative` which also matches. I am using the following code:

```
import re

name='ABC SCHOOL FOUNDATION COOPERATIVE PARTNERSHIP'
regex='(community contribution company|foundation cooperative partnership|cooperative|foundation)(?=\s)'

found= re.findall(regex, name.lower())

print(found)
```

How can I make regex to continue with the next words `COOPERATIVE PARTNERSHIP` after analyzing `FOUNDATION` instead of giving up when finding `foundation` and then `cooperative` separately?

Thanks again

Comment: Use `\b` or `(?=\s|$)` instead of `(?=\s)` because `(?=\s)` declares that a whitespace char **must** follow but there is no whitepsace at the end of your `name` string.

Comment: And adding `\b` at the start wouldn't hurt either (so you're always matching whole words).

Comment: Use `(?!\S)` if you want to treat a trailing punctuation as part of a word.

Comment: You will want to use `r`  in front of your regex pattern to escape the backslash and make it literal (treat it as a raw string) or non of your fixes will work

Comment: Your pattern won't match `foundation cooperative partnership` in the input string in your example, even if you got it to stop stop matching `foundation` and `cooperative` individually, because `partnership` isn't followed by a whitespace character.

Comment: And just another small note: You could also incorporate the ignorecase modifier directly in your pattern > `(?i)...rest of your pattern` or use `re.IGNORECASE` in the flags paramter of `re.findall`. Though your `lower()` function does also do the trick =)

Answer (score 0):

Change `(?=\s)` to `\b` to match a word boundary. There's no space at the end of the string, so the lookahead fails when it tries to match the whole string.

And almost always use a raw string for regular expressions, so that the regexp escape sequences won't be processed as string escape sequences.

```
>>> regex=r'(community contribution company|foundation cooperative partnership|cooperative|foundation)\b'
>>> re.findall(regex, name.lower())
['foundation cooperative partnership']
```